# Why wont MVC3 bind this (JSON)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

im really new to MVC and modelbinding so i guess im making something trival wrong, i try to bind some data;

View;

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Moo")',
            type: "post",
            dataType: "string",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({"test": "bar", "test2": "bar2"}),
            success: function (data) {}       
    });
```

Model;

```
Public Class MyTestData

     Public Property test() As String
     Public Property test2() As String

End Class
```

Controller;

```
Function Moo(test As MyTestData) As ActionResult

    Return View()
End Function
```

When i run the dubugger i recive "nothing" from test in the controller, if i try with only one string the code works (the data in the view changed to {(test:bar)} and the controller datatype changed to from MytestData to String).

Any input is appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your action parameter. It's called `test` and conflicting with the `test` property that you have inside:

```
Function Moo(model As MyTestData) As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

I guess you got too many tests :-) `FooBar` seems like a better name :-)

Joke aside you also have a problem with the `dataType` parameter. There's no such value as `string`. With ASP.NET MVC you usually do not need to supply it because the framework properly sets the HTTP Content-Type response header and jQuery will use it in order to parse the result automatically. So simply get rid of it, or make sure you have specified it to a correct value to match your actual return type. Since your action returns a view you could set it to `dataType: 'html'` in order to be consistent.